# Simultaneous matching of all Caesar rotations of a pattern in a text

Tags: strings, substrings, string-matching, exact-string-matching

Suppose we have an alphabet of size $S$, a pattern of length $P$ and a text of length $T$. We want to design an algorithm for matching all [caesar rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) of the pattern $P$ in the text $T$.  The problem can be solved using the following two methods:

- By $\text{KMP/Z}$ against all $S$ rotations of $P$ in time $O(P+ST)$ (we
  can reuse the $\text{LPS/Z}$ array of the pattern).
- By $\text{Aho-Corasick}$ against all $S$ rotations of $P$ in time $O(SP+T)$ by preinserting all the rotations into an automaton.

**Question:** Can the problem be solved in $O(P+T)$ time?

Comment: "This can be solved:" - What can be solved?  What does "this" refer to?  I suggest that you [edit] your post to state the problem in a self-contained way: specify both the input and the desired output.  You list the inputs $S,P,T$, but not the output or how it relates to the inputs.  What does "solved in $P+T$" mean?  Are you referring to running time?

Comment: What does "matching all rotations" mean?  Do you want to output all matches for each possible rotation of $P$?  Output all rotations of $P$ that have at least one match in $T$?  Check whether there exists any rotation of $P$ that matches $T$?  Something else?

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this problem?  If it is a practical problem you experienced, can you provide the motivation?  If it is a task you saw somewhere, can you provide a reference for the source where you saw it?

Comment: Hint: Match the differences between adjacent symbols in the alphabet.

Comment: @D.W. the original version is a programming excercise (without the $O(P+T)$ requirement, which is just my curiosity). Reporting if (yes/no) a match is found for each rotation should be enough, Though reporting the exact location of each match shouldn't hit complexity, as every rotation is pairwise distinct and never a prefix of another, each position in the text matches at most one pattern rotation.

Comment: @Pseudonym I did explore that path! Dunno why I didn't see it, thanks!. Would you like to do the full answer or should I self-answer?

Comment: @chubakuenom I think answering your own question would be educational.

Comment: Great. Please [edit] the question to incorporate that information into the question, then flag comments as 'no longer needed'.  We want questions to be self-contained, so they read well and contain all necessary information for the reader, for readers who encounter this for the first time, without people having to read the comments to understand relevant context and motivation and specification of the problem statement.